Why's my lambda function exiting before stream finishes?
I have a lambda function which is reading from an S3 file triggered from an S3 ObjectCreate event. The file contains about 80,000 rows of csv which I'm trying to save to DynamoDB using batchWrite. It seems to work fine, but the lambda function exits after saving about 400 records usually around 1-2seconds. The lambda timeout is set to 5 mins. It doesn't timeout, or run out of memory. It doesn't give any error at all, just the usual lambda exit message. What am I missing?
// inside lambda
try {
    const s3Response = await s3.getObject(s3Params).promise()
    await doImport(s3Response.Body)
} catch (e) {
     console.error(e, e)
}

import {Readable, Transform} from "node:stream";
import {pipeline} from "node:stream/promises";

async doImport(data) {
    const parser = parse({
        header: true,
        columns: true,
        skip_empty_lines: true,
        delimiter: ','
    })
    const dbStream = new DbStream()
    try {
        await pipeline(
            Readable.from(data),
            parser,
            new ObjectCollector({chunkSize: 25}),
            dbStream
        );
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error in pipeline.", e);
        throw e;
    }
}

class ObjectCollector extends Transform {

    constructor({chunkSize}) {
        super({objectMode: true});
        this.buffer = [];
        this.chunkSize = chunkSize;
    }

    _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        this.buffer.push(chunk);
        if(this.buffer.length >= this.chunkSize) {
            this.push(this.buffer);
            this.buffer.length = 0;
        }
        callback();
    }

    _flush(callback) {
        this.push(this.buffer);
        callback();
    }
}

class DbStream extends Transform {
    constructor() {
        super({objectMode: true});
    }

    _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        // calls DynamoDB batchWrite
        // Promise resolves after all records in chunk have been written to dynamodb
        dbService.saveAll(chunk).then(() => {
            callback(null, chunk)
        });
    }
}

Logs
2024-04-11T17:58:20.611+02:00   START RequestId: ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 Version: $LATEST
2024-04-11T17:58:20.613+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:20.613Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO S3 Import Event: { Records: [ { eventVersion: '2.1', eventSource: 'aws:s3', awsRegion: 'ap-southeast-2', eventTime: '2024-04-11T15:58:18.115Z', eventName: 'ObjectCreated:Put', userIdentity: [Object], requestParameters: [Object], responseElements: [Object], s3: [Object] } ] }
2024-04-11T17:58:20.755+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:20.755Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Saving 25...
2024-04-11T17:58:20.756+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:20.756Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Service.saveAll true. 25 items
2024-04-11T17:58:21.428+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.428Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Saving 25...
2024-04-11T17:58:21.429+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.429Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Service.saveAll true. 25 items
2024-04-11T17:58:21.446+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.446Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Saving 25...
2024-04-11T17:58:21.446+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.446Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Service.saveAll true. 25 items
2024-04-11T17:58:21.461+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.461Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Saving 25...
2024-04-11T17:58:21.462+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.462Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Service.saveAll true. 25 items
2024-04-11T17:58:21.477+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.477Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Saving 25...
2024-04-11T17:58:21.477+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.477Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Service.saveAll true. 25 items
2024-04-11T17:58:21.493+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.493Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Saving 25...
2024-04-11T17:58:21.493+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.493Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Service.saveAll true. 25 items
2024-04-11T17:58:21.510+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.510Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Saving 25...
2024-04-11T17:58:21.510+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.510Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Service.saveAll true. 25 items
2024-04-11T17:58:21.528+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.528Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Saving 25...
2024-04-11T17:58:21.528+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.528Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Service.saveAll true. 25 items
2024-04-11T17:58:21.566+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.566Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Saving 25...
2024-04-11T17:58:21.566+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.566Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Service.saveAll true. 25 items
2024-04-11T17:58:21.580+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.580Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Saving 25...
2024-04-11T17:58:21.580+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.580Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Service.saveAll true. 25 items
2024-04-11T17:58:21.592+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.592Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Saving 25...
2024-04-11T17:58:21.592+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.592Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Service.saveAll true. 25 items
2024-04-11T17:58:21.605+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.605Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Saving 25...
2024-04-11T17:58:21.605+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.605Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Service.saveAll true. 25 items
2024-04-11T17:58:21.617+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.617Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Saving 25...
2024-04-11T17:58:21.617+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.617Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Service.saveAll true. 25 items
2024-04-11T17:58:21.631+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.631Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Saving 25...
2024-04-11T17:58:21.631+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.631Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Service.saveAll true. 25 items
2024-04-11T17:58:21.642+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.642Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Saving 25...
2024-04-11T17:58:21.642+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.642Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Service.saveAll true. 25 items
2024-04-11T17:58:21.654+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.654Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Saving 25...
2024-04-11T17:58:21.654+02:00   2024-04-11T15:58:21.654Z ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 INFO Service.saveAll true. 25 items
2024-04-11T17:58:21.666+02:00   END RequestId: ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372
2024-04-11T17:58:21.666+02:00   REPORT RequestId: ce561a77-2f35-4801-9f76-36dede9cb372 Duration: 1055.05 ms Billed Duration: 1056 ms Memory Size: 4096 MB Max Memory Used: 278 MB Init Duration: 1035.18 ms XRAY TraceId: 1-6618089b-2c5e927f59c8180d0f0e9c85 SegmentId: 7668db7d26b84927 Sampled: true

Anyone there?

Could you add the lambda logs too?

It doesn't give any error at all,  we'd like to see that... maybe having a log lone after each chunk could give more insight

Does this solution guarantee that it won't process a chunk of data that is not an exact multiple of lines from the CSV file (e.g. it contains a partial last line of CSV text and the next chunk begins with the remainder of that same line of CSV text)?

Ok, added the logs. One other bit of info I missed was that the lambda is triggered by an S3 ObjectCreate event... if that makes any difference.

@jarmod I am using csv-parse to parse the CSV file. I'll add the csv options to the question.
